# Relative Paths in SoapUI

Tags: maven, automated-tests, soapui

Is it possible to have SoapUI *save* relative paths to external data sets?

A tester on my team saves the SoapUI project, specifying that the `ResourceRoot` is `${projectDir}`. The `TestDataSheet` properties are then specified as relative paths, (eg `TC_Authenticate_AN_5.xls`, noting no directory information). When he saves the file though, SoapUI decides to substitute the relative path for an absolute path, resulting in the file having entries like:

```
<con:property>
    <con:name>TestDataSheet</con:name>
    <con:value>C:\Users\username\git\riga\riga-soapui\src\test\soapui\TC_Authenticate_AN_5.xls</con:value>
</con:property>
```

When we try to run the tests using the Maven SoapUI Plugin the data loads fail because the file system is completely different.

Surely we can't be the first people to encounter this problem? Is there any way of stopping SoapUI doing this?

Comment: Have you tried [relative path in soapUI](http://www.soapui.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=7653)?

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked to change the path to

`<con:value>../TC_Authenticate_AN_5.xls</con:value>`

This seems to work cross-platform. Your source folder would be the SoapUI install directory then.

Answer (score 0):

I bypassed this situation by defining the resource root in file -> Preferences -> General Properties
I add there a new property called ResourceRoot with the value

```
    ${projectDir}\MyResourceFolder
```

(or don't use MyResourceFolder if you want it straight in the project folder). Then later, in the code, I use

```
    context.expand('${#Global#ResourceRoot}')
```

to access the folder.